# Android receiving images over tcp socket from c# server

Tags: c#, java, android, android-networking

I'm perfectly receiving images in `Android` from `C# Server` and streaming video. Problem is, I'm always opening and closing socket for each image. How can I receive images on creating a single socket only. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    etip=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
//  etip.setText("192.168.1.5");
    etip.setText("10.0.2.2");
    imgview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
             try {
                    serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(etip.getText().toString());
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                    Log.d("TCP", "C: Connecting..."); 
            }
            finally
            {

            }
            try
            {
                {
                 mHandler = new Handler();
                      mHandler.post(connectSocket);
                }       

}
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }

    });
}

    private Runnable connectSocket=new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            {
                try { 
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 4444);
                            DataInputStream dis;
                            try { 
                                dis=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                                int bytesRead;
                                byte[] pic = new byte[5000*1024];
                                bytesRead = dis.read(pic, 0, pic.length);
                                 bitmapimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(pic, 0, bytesRead);              


                            } catch(Exception e) { 
                                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e); 
                            } finally { 
                                socket.close(); 
                            } 

                        } catch (UnknownHostException e) { 
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                            Log.e("TCP", "C: UnknownHostException", e); 
                            e.printStackTrace(); 
                        } catch (IOException e) { 
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                            Log.e("TCP", "C: IOException", e); 
                            e.printStackTrace(); 
                        }
                        imgview.setImageBitmap(bitmapimage);
                        imgview.invalidate();

    }
             mHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }   //run end
    };


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The socket won't close until you tell it to close like

```
socket.close();
```

*FYI, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close()   socket close function is also going to close any associative input/output streams*

or the thread/application dies.

To make your application/thread constantly waits and reads,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read(byte[])

*Reads some number of bytes from the contained input stream and stores them into the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as an integer. This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.*

use read function of inputstream inside a loop and let it read new data whenever they are available.

However, I recommend you to try reduce number of socket connections as much as possible by limiting maximum socket connections and etc. This might prevent some attackers who want to just open up large amount of socket connections and do nothing to your server.

Comment: i want to stream video on single socket but i dont know how to do this .i'll be thankfull to u if u guide me

Comment: Streaming media can be quite difficult or you can make this very easy ways. However, streaming is quite costly so you need to plan carefully (architecturing server) if this application is intended to go on the market. I recommend you to use streaming server solutions like Wowza for this. Here is a tutorial from their website http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?36-How-to-publish-and-play-a-live-stream-(RTMP-or-RTSP-RTP-based-encoder)

Comment: Then you need to provide rtsp url that goes like rtsp://something.com  to mediaview. This process is quite easy because it is already built in

Comment: is it possible to receive and display multiple images over single socket ?